# Как скинуть функцию .hover() на тач девайсе?

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover

Всегда думал что `.hover()` сработает и на таче (как и css вероятно), но оказалось что нет. Вроде кое-как и работает, но увы только в одну сторону - на тач устройстве `.hover` - аналог клика, то есть класс вешается но как его убрать?

[codepen](https://codepen.io/grdnk/pen/NWaYreK)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.helper__button').hover(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.helper__popup').toggleClass('show')
  })
});
```

```css
.helper__popup {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px;
  background: #eee;
  border: 1px dashed #333;
  margin-top: 10px;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}
.helper__popup.show {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="helper">
  <button class="helper__button">?</button>
  <div class="helper__popup">
    any hidden content
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: кликнуть в другое место (по другому элементу)

Comment: @humster_spb делал это рассчитывая как раз на то что такое поведение сработает, но по факту нет

Comment: ну что значит "по факту нет". Ховер на мобильных устройствах именно так и работает. Значит, Вы куда-то не туда кликаете.

Answer (score 2):

**Здравствуйте!** Попробуйте это.

CSS:

```
.helper__popup.hide {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.helper__button').hover(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $('.helper__popup').toggleClass('show')
  }, function(){
      $('.helper__popup').toggleClass('hide')
  });
});
```

Не уверен что сработает, но по идее должно, и всё же если не сработает то попробуйте по такой схеме:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.helper__button').mouseenter(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $('.helper__popup').toggleClass('show')
  })
    $('.helper__button').mouseleave(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $('.helper__popup').toggleClass('hide')
  })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

CSS вполне достаточно

```css
.helper__popup {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px;
  background: #eee;
  border: 1px dashed #333;
  margin-top: 10px;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}
button:active ~ .helper__popup,
button:hover ~ .helper__popup{
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="helper">
  <button class="helper__button">?</button>
  <div>content</div>
  <div class="helper__popup">
    any hidden content
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: хороший выход из положения, но увы у меня эти блоки далеко не по соседству)

Comment: @emptyman Они могут быть не по соседству.